# Javascript / jQuery - How to highlight subscript / superscript in search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, highlight

I have a search functionality. I need to highlight a word even the subscript / superscript.

For example if I search for h<sup>2</sup>o, I should highlight the h<sup>2</sup>o. But my code actually changes it to h2o and displays the result.

```js
$('#searchfor').keyup(function() {
  var page = $('#all_text');
  var test = $('#searchfor').innerHtml;
  var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>");
  var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
  var theRegEx = new RegExp("(" + searchedText + ")", "g");
  var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx, "<span>$1</span>");
  page.html(newHtml);
});
```

```css
#all_text span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchfor" />
<p id="all_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, h<sup>2</sup>o consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
  nibh euismod tinci futurum.</p>
```

Comment: Because `page.text()` strips all HTML from the page - the first keyup has already removed all HTML - so the "h" in "h2o" removes the sup from the page

Comment: Yes. So what should be the fix?

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for referring. This answers my question.

Comment: Try [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).